# Store input from text field into a different table than the primary form builder model? - Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

**TL;DR**

I want to check my `Coupon` table when a new user registers to see if that Coupon Code exists. If it does, apply the appropriate discount i.e. `coupon.discount_amount` to that new user's account. But this is just on one field in the `new user registration` form (the form which belongs to the `User` model).

**Long Version**

I am using Devise to manage my User registration and logins.

So this is what my `registration/new/index.html.erb` view looks like:

```
<% @user.plan_id = params[:plan_id] %>

    <%= devise_error_messages! %><br />

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

        <% if !params[:promo] %>
        <%= f.collection_select :plan_id, @plan, :id, :display_name, :prompt => "Choose yourself up a real nice plan" %><br />
        <% end %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Desired Username" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First Name" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name" %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Password" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email Address" %><br />
        <% if params[:promo] %>
            <%= f.text_field :xcode, :placeholder => "Coupon Code" %><br /> 
        <% end %>
        <div class="settings_button">
            <%= f.submit "Sign in", :id => "register", :value => "Register", :class => "pill button" %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

The line in question is the line that says `<%= f.text_field :xcode, :placeholder => "Coupon Code" %><br />`.

Every other field corresponds to a column in my `User` model...but this one should correspond to an association that's pretty complex.

For instance, say `test = User.find('test')`.

Then the Coupon_Code entered by `Test`, would be stored in `test.subscriptions.last.coupon.code`.

So I want to do two things...when `Test` enters coupon code: `4gHu7k`, I want to do a `Coupon.find('4gHu7k')`. If it does exist, then I want to set the following (assuming that this new coupon would have an ID of `5`): `test.subscriptions.last.coupon_id`.

The schema for my Subscription model is as follows:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :plan
    has_one :coupon
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: subscriptions
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  status               :string(255)
#  plan_id              :integer
#  payment_method_token :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  user_id              :integer
#  period_start         :datetime
#  period_end           :datetime
#  coupon_id            :integer
#
```

I hope I have explained what I need clearly, let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks.

P.S. When I run it as is, I get the following:

```
undefined method `xcode' for #<User:0x00000103583d70>
```

Which is around that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest instead of using f.text_field, why dont you try text_field_tag?
<%= text_field_tag "sample" %>

Now you can access this value in controller as params[:sample].
Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you use my code to show me that example. Because as far as I know it, f.text_field is basically the same thing. But I could be mistaken, so please give me some more info, so I can understand fully. Thanks.

Comment: Also, not quite sure I understand what you mean.